# Efficient Way to Keep Checking if Auto Increment Value has Changed

Tags: java, mysql

I am writing a Java program that needs to continue checking if the auto increment value of a given database table has changed. Currently, the program does this by querying the database in an infinite loop on a separate thread.

```
public class StackOverflow implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            // Assume that 'currentMessageID' has already been declared as type integer
            // and that 'getLatestMessageID()' queries the database.
            if(currentMessageID < queryHandler.getLatestMessageID())
            {
                int latestMessageID = queryHandler.getLatestMessageID();
                for(int x = ajaxChat.currentMessageID + 1; x <= latestMessageID; x++)
                {
                    // Do something when the auto increment value is greater than the last
                    // known auto increment value.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While this works just fine, it puts a significant strain on the database server since

```
SELECT `auto_increment` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name = 'SOrocks'
```

is being called over and over. Is there any way that I could watch for the auto increment value to change without hammering the database server with the same query over and over again?

Comment: This might help- [link](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39522/execution-of-a-java-program-by-a-trigger)

Comment: That depends on why you are doing this. Assuming this is some kind of chat application, you could use some event mechanism (i.e. the part which writes the entry to the database sends an event to a listener, and the listener then does some work).

Comment: @dunni The application is for allowing communication between two installations of [AJAX Chat](https://frug.github.io/AJAX-Chat/). Because those who will be using the program are not tech savvy, I need to do as much within the application as possible without relying on modifying the AJAX Chat source code or its database.

Comment: @Abhishek Thank you, but unfortunately, I have no idea what is being discussed in the question you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Unluckyly if you can work only from the application side, a thread that polls the db is the only solution which comes to my mind BUT, if you can also change the DB side, you can always make a trigger on the database to call your java method ([example with Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/java.815/a64686/04_call2.htm)).